# React jest - You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a super simple react app like so.

- index.tsx
- App.tsx
- Main.tsx
- Home.tsx

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import client from "./utils/client";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from "./Main";

function App() {
  return (
    <Main />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Home";

const Main:React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Home.tsx

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home:React.FC = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>

            <Link to='http://google.com'> Google</Link>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

I have an App.test.tsx with a dummy test just to run it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(true).toBeTruthy
});
```

If I run the test with `yarn test`

I get an error:

> Invariant failed: You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`

The Link I have is in `Home.tsc` which is surrounded by `<Router>` in `index.tsx`

I'm I doing something work here.

The app runs without any errors.

This error only appears when I run the test

Comment: show your test file witch create this warning. maybe test file create some Link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions below, the first is to add `<Router>` component into your test case. The second option is to switch from `<Link>` to a simple [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

**Option 1:**

You can add `<Router>` component into your test also, so it won't missing there as:

```
test('renders learn react link', () => {
  render(<Router>
    <App />
  </Router>);

  expect(true).toBeTruthy
});
```

**Option 2:**

Also you can change from `<Link>` component to a simple anchor tag because it creates the same end result based on your code from:

```
<Link to='http://google.com'> Google</Link>
```

To the following in `<Home>` component:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Then at the end you can keep your original test case.